# Different signingConfig in Multidimensional build flavors just for Release buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using following configuration:

```
android {
// a lot more of definitions...

signingConfigs {
    // For advanced-artefacts, we are using a different signing configuration in each environment
    advanced_prod {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE_advanced)
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS_ADVANCED
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
    }
    advanced_int {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE_advanced)
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
        keyAlias "advancedapp.android.int"
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
    }
    advanced_test {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE_advanced)
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
        keyAlias "advancedapp.android.test"
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
    }
    advanced_dev {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE_advanced)
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
        keyAlias "advancedapp.android.dev"
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD_ADVANCED
    }
    basic {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE_BASIC)
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_BASIC
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS_BASIC
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD_BASIC
        storeType "JKS"
    }
}

flavorDimensions "project", "environment"

productFlavors {
    basic {
        dimension "project"
    }
    advanced {
        dimension "project"
    }
    flavorDevelopment {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.domain.superapp.development"
    }

    flavorTest {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.domain.superapp.test"
    }

    flavorIntegration {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.domain.superapp.integration"
    }

    flavorProduction {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.domain.superapp.production"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        // all debug artefacts are signed with the default, the android debug certificate from the local machine
     }

    release {
        // Currently all environments (dev/test/int/prod) are signed by the Production certificates either for basic or for advanced
        productFlavors.basic.signingConfig signingConfigs.basic
        productFlavors.advanced.signingConfig signingConfigs.advanced_prod // <- !!! here my question relates to !!!

    }
}


// a lot more of definitions...
}
```

This configuration will create following build-Variants:

advancedFlavorDevelopmentRelease -> signingConfig: advanced_dev 
advancedFlavorTestRelease -> signingConfig: advanced_test 
advancedFlavorIntegrationRelease -> signingConfig: advanced_int 
advancedFlavorProductionRelease -> signingConfig: advanced_prod 
advancedFlavorDevelopmentDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local) 
advancedFlavorTestDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)
advancedFlavorIntegrationDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)
advancedFlavorProductionDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)

basicFlavorDevelopmentRelease  -> signingConfig: basic 
basicFlavorTestRelease  -> signingConfig: basic 
basicFlavorIntegrationRelease  -> signingConfig: basic 
basicFlavorProductionRelease  -> signingConfig: basic 
basicFlavorDevelopmentDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)
basicFlavorTestDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)
basicFlavorIntegrationDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)
basicFlavorProductionDebug -> signingConfig: android_debug (local)

My Question is relating to following code:
productFlavors.advanced.signingConfig signingConfigs.advanced_prod 
Currently I'm assigning all environments from the advanced Flavor the advanced_prod certificate
the certification need for the basic version is fine and done with above configuration!

I made a trial which was not successful:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == 'advancedFlavorDevelopmentRelease') {
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        flavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.advanced_dev;
    }
    if (variant.name == 'advancedFlavorTestRelease') {
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        flavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.advanced_test;
    }
    if (variant.name == 'advancedFlavorIntegrationRelease') {
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        flavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.advanced_int;
    }
    if (variant.name == 'advancedFlavorProductionRelease') {
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        flavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.advanced_prod;
    }
}
```

**I'm searching for a solution to customize the advanced Product to configure a dedicated signConfig for each environment (flavorDevelopment/flavorTest/flavorIntegration) but only in release buildType**

any Ideas?

Luke

Comment: If does not work as the interface Product flavor only has getSigningConfig method and not setSigningConfig.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same situation, here is my solution and it works for me.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        flavorA {
            storeFile file("xxx.jks")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }

        flavorB {
            storeFile file("xxx.jks")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

            flavorA {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.flavorA
            }

            flavorB {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.flavorB
            }
        }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug.init(release.signingConfig)
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }

    }
}
```

And my AndroidStudio is 3.6.2 and AGP is 3.6.2.

Hope it can help you !

Comment: How do we do it for kotlin DSL?